# Make the layout use the transformed coordinate (CSS)

Tags: html, css, transformation, css-transforms

Is there a way to make HTML/CSS to use the transformed coordinates in layout calculations? E.g. if I scale a div, I want the next div to automatically start on the scaled div's boundary.

```css
body {
  padding:50px;
}

.a {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  transform:scale(1.2)
}

.b {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  hello
</div>

<div class="b">
  world
</div>
```

Comment: no, it's not possible

Comment: it's seems you want a fix for this particular example. In this case, use `transform-origin: bottom;` on the transformed element and you don't need any calculation

Comment: Actually I meant in general.

Comment: but you accepted an answer that fix your particular case so it's not in general

Comment: I accepted it because it explains that what I wanted is not working by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to make HTML/CSS to use the transformed coordinates in layout calculations?

Yes, that's what the `transform` property is for.

However, `transform` (like many other properties) only applies to an element and its descendants *not* its siblings. This is by-design. Furthermore, properties like `transform` (and `opacity`, and others) create a new *stacking context* which basically messes-up z-index ordering.

Anyway, to get what you want, you can use a different approach: as you're using a constant scale of `1.2` you can use that to calculate a positive bottom margin on `.a` to *bump* siblings down, like so:

```css
body {
  padding:50px;
}

.a {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  transform: scale(1.2); /* i.e. 1.0 + 0.2 */
  margin-bottom: 10px; /* ( 0.2 * 100px ) / 2 // the divide-by-2 is because the scale is centered, so a 20% total scale results in a 10% scale at each end of the axis */
}

.b {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
  <div class="a">
    hello
  </div>

  <div class="b">
    world
  </div>
```